# Searching all Databases Code Error Not Sure Why

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

My code is below, I am getting the following error message, but I'm not sure why:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37 Incorrect syntax near '

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
 use [NA];
    go
    -----------------------------
        exec sp_MSforeachDB
    '
        use ?;

        select top 1
            db_name() as [database_name],
            s.[name] as [schema_name],
            b.[name] as [object_name],
            b.[type] as [object_type],
            case
                when b.[type] = ''P''  then ''SQL Stored Procedure''
                when b.[type] = ''RF'' then ''Replication-filter-procedure''
                when b.[type] = ''V''  then ''View''
                when b.[type] = ''TR'' then ''SQL DML Trigger''
                when b.[type] = ''FN'' then ''SQL Scalar Function''
                when b.[type] = ''IF'' then ''SQL inline table-valued function''
                when b.[type] = ''TF'' then ''SQL Table-Valued Function''
                when b.[type] = ''R''  then ''Rule (old-style, stand-alone)''
                else ''
                end as [object_type_description],
            --------------------
            a.[object_id],
            object_definition(a.[object_id]) as [object_definition_results]
            --------------------
        from
            [sys].[sql_modules] as a
        inner join
            [sys].[objects] as b
            on
                a.[object_id] = b.[object_id]
        inner join
            [sys].[schemas] as s
            on
                b.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
        where
            object_definition(a.[object_id]) like ''%SchlGrpTestSchlName%''
    '
```

Comment: I think your else should probably be 4 single quotes, which would end up escaping to an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing your query by building into a variable it was clear the error is

```
else ''
```

this should be

```
else ''''
```

otherwise it's not properly embedding the single quotes into the string.